# Create DateTime from string without applying timezone or daylight savings

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, datetime-parsing

How do I create a DateTime var from a string which is already adjusted for UTC?  I am running this on a machine set to BST (GMT+1).  If I run the following line of code:

```
DateTime clientsideProfileSyncStamp = Convert.ToDateTime("20-May-2011 15:20:00");
```

and then use the value in a test against a database holding (UTC) values then it would appear that the Convert.ToDateTime() is actually giving me a UTC value of 14:20.  I don't want it to do the conversion - I just want it to accept that my DateTime string is already in UTC.

Thanks.

Comment: When I just tried `Convert.ToDateTime()`, it returned the exact value that the string represents. Are you calling `.ToUniversalTime()`? What are you doing with the value after you do the conversion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Parse the string, and specify that it should assume UTC time when there is no time zone specified in the string:

```
DateTime clientsideProfileSyncStamp =
  DateTime.Parse(
    "20-May-2011 15:20:00",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
  );
```

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse
```

The under-advertised [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) type represents a point in time regardless of timezone differences, and as such should be used in preference to DateTime where a 'timestamp' is required.

Comment: looks good.  I need to then pass it to a 3rd-party API that is expecting a std DateTime - what is the safest way to convert it to the DateTime?

Comment: @Journeyman, just access the `DateTime` property of the `DateTimeOffset` variable: `dtVar = dtoffsetVar.DateTime`

Answer (score 7):

@Guffa's answer is very good but i will like to add an additional answer.
If your datetime string is looking like this "2017-11-27T05:30:00.000Z" then AssumeUniversal is not working. 
Try this :

```
    DateTime.Parse("2017-11-27T05:30:00.000Z", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

There is a slight difference between AssumeUniversal and AdjustToUniversal. Read here : [Difference between AssumeUniversal and AdjustToUniversal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `Z` to the DateTime string:

```
DateTime clientsideProfileSyncStamp = Convert.ToDateTime("20-May-2011 15:20:00Z");
Console.Write(clientsideProfileSyncStamp.ToUniversalTime()); // 20-May-2011 15:20:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the `TryParse` variant which allows you to handle a parse error without an exception

```
DateTime clientsideProfileSyncStamp;
DateTime.TryParse(
    "20-May-2011 15:20:00",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal,
    out clientsideProfileSyncStamp
);
```

Also if you are not using `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` it will assume the output `Kind` is `Local` so you may also want to use `ToUniversalTime()`

```
clientsideProfileSyncStamp.ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()`

```
var clientsideProfileSyncStamp = DateTime.Parse("20-May-2011 15:20:00");
```

Answer (score -1):

To create culture independent DateTime use:

```
DateTime.Parse("2022-02-15 09:30:47", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then the date stays always exactly as defined in string.